# Base class not finding app settings

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

This is somewhat of a general question but I haven't found much by googling it. I have a test framework that sets up an environment for testing purposes. My application consumes this framework through a reference path and runs manual tests just fine. However, once I ask the build server to run my test the framework complains it cannot find any of my app settings. The app.config file sits in my testing project for my application and I am sure it exists in the correct bin folder on my build server. I'm doing this in a C# .NET environment.

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure what to be more specific about. I would imagine it's something with the build server since it seems to work running tests locally but I have no clue what to look at. Nothing else about the build server is failing, just getting the app settings.

The framework is .NET 4.0 while the main project is 4.5. I'm using nunit to run the tests and running them outside the build process but using the Nunit gui fails at the same point.

The code that grabs the app settings is pretty basic:

```
string databaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseName"];
```

**EDIT**

Snippet of my test:

```
public class UserServiceTests : DeployDBEveryFixtureBase
    {
        public UserServiceTests()
        {
            DBSetup("Core");
            DBSetup("Postal");
            DBSetup("Common");
        }

        private UserService userService = new UserService(string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};",
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["targetServer"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseName"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userID"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]));

        [Test]
        public void UserService_Get()
        {
            // Act
            User user = userService.GetUser(Guid.Empty, "*****", string.Empty);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(user.FirstName == "System");
        }
    }
```

The environment deployment is in the base class of DeployDBEveryFixtureBase. The DBSetup calls ensure that each database is deployed in the proper order. All of those seem to run fine and my tests complete but I still get the described error. If I look at the database I can all the datbases being properly deployed and then removed (the base class includes a TestFixtureTearDown) but it seems like the build process is trying to run it again.

Note: I am only building the solution file during this process. I do not currently have a .proj file in the build.

Comment: This way to broad, be more specific. The problem can be either in your system or build server

Comment: Can you add some tracing or something like that on your build server just to be sure, that the code gets executed in the right directory with the app.config nearby?

Comment: For quick check, put your test app.config file in same folder where you have been having your NUnit assembly files of your test project and try to test on NUnit on GUI.

Comment: It must be an issue with our build process. I can see the environment being set up and torn down, which uses the app settings, but something else must be rerunning the tests when the app.config file is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your build server or how exactly you run your tests there is only one issue which comes to mind, that is Shadow Copying.  Can you check if your unit tested DLLs are not shadow copied to some location where the app.config file doesn't exist?

Comment: I've checked and double checked that but the registry is set to not shadow copy.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, would you be able to share a snippet of your config file and the unit tests which fails?  Just so we can be a bit more helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my testing framework had an empty constructor that wasn't so empty. It looks like the app.config was being properly queried but was returning an empty result set since the empty constructor did not have the proper arguments. After removing the contents of the empty constructor my test ran fine. Thank you all for the help.